# How to add the misfire gracetime and coalesce in the active jobs in apscheduler?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, cron-task, apscheduler

I have 1000 active jobs in the apscheduler(3.0.1).I wanted to add **misfire_grace_time** and **coalesce** to all these scheduler jobs.
Since these fields can only be added while creating the jobs.
Is there any other way to add them?
One solution I can think is to delete all the jobs and then add all of them.
Here is the code snippet:

Active Job:

```
  scheduler = get_scheduler()
  scheduler.add_job(executor_job, trigger='interval',seconds=100, id="sch:exe:1",
                  replace_existing=False)
  scheduler.start()
```

Updated Configuration should be like for the job:

```
  scheduler.add_job(executor_job, trigger='interval',seconds=100, id="sch:exe:1",
                  replace_existing=False,misfire_grace_time=900,coalesce=True)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you're saying these fields can only be added while creating the jobs, but take a look at these:

- [modify_job()](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/schedulers/base.html#apscheduler.schedulers.base.BaseScheduler.modify_job)
- [get_jobs()](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/schedulers/base.html#apscheduler.schedulers.base.BaseScheduler.get_jobs)